# Python - Tkinter Freezing w/ PyHook

Tags: python, tkinter

I've built a counter that I've tested to work along with another game I play.  Now I want to utilize Tkinter GUI to display this counter as it increases.

I loosely understand that there is an issue with running the mainloop from Tkinter at the same time as running the PumpMessages portion necessary for my PyHook.  I've tried googling snippets of code to make corrections, but I can't find anything that I can plug in.

How do I update my code so that the Tkinter GUI doesn't just freeze?

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, win32api, win32con, time, ctypes
from Tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

Fc, JKc = 0, 0
x, j, i = '', '', ''

def killProgram():
    ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)
    root.destroy()
    rootThread.join()

#this is my counter input
def onKeyboardEvent(event): 
    global i, x, Fc, JKc, j
    i = event.Key
    if i=='F4':
        killProgram
    elif i=='Return':
        if 'f ' == x[:2] and len(x) >= 3:
            Fc = Fc + 1
        elif 'jk ' == x[:3] and len(x) >= 4:
            JKc = JKc + 1
       j = x
        x = ''
    elif i=='Up':
        x = j
    else:
        x = x + chr(event.Ascii)
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = onKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()

#My GUI
root = Tk()

wlabel = Label(root, text='Weapon')
wlabel.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NE')

hlabel = Label(root, text='Hand')
hlabel.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='N')

alabel = Label(root, text='All')
alabel.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky='NW')

wc = StringVar()
wcounter = Label(root, textvariable = wc)
wcounter.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='SE')

hc = StringVar()
hcounter = Label(root, textvariable = hc)
hcounter.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='S')

ac = StringVar()
acounter = Label(root, textvariable=ac)
acounter.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='SW')

def startTimerThread():
    while True:
        win32api.PostThreadMessage(mainThreadId, win32con.WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
        time.sleep(1)

mainThreadId = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
timerThread = Thread(target=startTimerThread)
timerThread.start()

#Updates Label
while runningProgram:
    hc.set(text=str(Jkc))
    #wc.set(text=str(Fc))
    #ac.set(text=str(Fc+JKc))
    root.after(100,root.quit)
    root.mainloop()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have `PumpMessages()` in a separate thread. Additionally, unless you want your GUI to freeze up shortly after starting, you want to delegate your `onKeyboardEvent()` to create individual threads as well, as that function needs to return `True` or `False` as quickly as possible.